# deleteを書いたはずなのに「delete」が定義されていないとエラーが出てしまう

Tags: flutter

[Flutterの教科書](https://zenn.dev/flutteruniv/books/flutter-textbook) 内の「『チャット』【後編】』でチャットページ内で編集ボタン＋削除ボタンを追加する作業を行ってみたのですが、そのうちの投稿を削除する機能を作成使用した所、「delete」に赤い波線が出て、エラーが出てしまいました。教科書通りに進めたはずですが、このコードで間違っている点はあるのでしょうか？？

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
The method 'delete' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'delete'.
```

**ソースコード:**

```dart
import 'package:chat_prime/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:chat_prime/my_page.dart';
import 'package:chat_prime/post.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  // main 関数でも async が使えます
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // runApp 前に何かを実行したいときはこれが必要です。
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    // これが Firebase の初期化処理です。
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.android,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null){
      return const MaterialApp(
        home: SignInPage(),
      );
    } else {
      return const MaterialApp(
        home: ChatPage(),
      );
    }
  }
}

class SignInPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignInPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignInPage> createState() => _SignInPageState();
}

class _SignInPageState extends State<SignInPage> {
  Future<void> signInWithGoogle() async {
    // GoogleSignIn をして得られた情報を Firebase と関連づけることをやっています。
    final googleUser = await GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['profile', 'email']).signIn();

    final googleAuth = await googleUser?.authentication;

    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
    );

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('GoogleSignIn'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('GoogleSignIn'),
          onPressed: () async {
            await signInWithGoogle();

            if (mounted){
               Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                    return const ChatPage();
                  }),
                  (route) => false,
                );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final postsReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').withConverter<Post>( // <> ここに変換したい型名をいれます。今回は Post です。
  fromFirestore: ((snapshot, _) { // 第二引数は使わないのでその場合は _ で不使用であることを分かりやすくしています。
    return Post.fromFirestore(snapshot); // 先ほど定期着した fromFirestore がここで活躍します。
  }),
  toFirestore: ((value, _) {
    return value.toMap(); // 先ほど適宜した toMap がここで活躍します。
  }),
);

class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget{
  const ChatPage({super.key});
  @override
  State<ChatPage> createState() => _ChatPageState();
}

class _ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('チャット'),
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: (){
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
                    return const MyPage();
                  },)
                );
              },
              child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.photoURL!,
              ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
            Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Post>>(
                  stream: postsReference.orderBy('createdAt').snapshots(),
                builder: (context,snapshot) {
                  final docs =snapshot.data?.docs??[];
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: docs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context,index){
                      final post = docs[index].data();
                      return PostWidget(post: post);
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField
            (
            onFieldSubmitted: (text) {
              final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

              final posterId = user.uid;
              final posterName = user.displayName!;
              final posterImageUrl = user.photoURL!;

              final newDocumentReference = postsReference.doc();

              final newPost = Post(
                text: text,
                createdAt: Timestamp.now(),
                posterName: posterName,
                posterImageUrl: posterImageUrl,
                posterId: posterId,
                reference: newDocumentReference,
              );
              newDocumentReference.set(newPost);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PostWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const PostWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.post,
  });

  final Post post;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(post.posterImageUrl),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 8),

           Expanded(
           child: Column(
             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
             children: [
               Row(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                 children: [
                   Text(
                     post.posterName,
                     style: const TextStyle(
                       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                       fontSize: 12,
                     ),
                   ),
                   Text(
                     // toDate() で Timestamp から DateTime に変換できます。
                     DateFormat('MM/dd HH:mm').format(post.createdAt.toDate()),
                     style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                  color : FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid == post.posterId ?
                   Colors.amber
                   : Colors.blue[100],
                ),
                child: Text(post.text),
              ),
              if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid == post.posterId)
              IconButton(
                onPressed: (){},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  postsReference.delete();
                },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              ),
             ],
           ),
         ),
       ],
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

[image: 現時点での状態]

Comment: 「deleteを書いたはず」といっても質問のソースコード上では「呼び出しているだけ」で、「定義」はされていないように見えます。「deleteを定義しているソースコード」があるなら、その部分を提示してみてください。それから何処でどんなエラーが発生したとかや状況はスクリーンショットではなくテキストで説明した方が良いでしょう。[スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765/26370) おそらく書籍からの転記・入力・作業を行った際に、あなたが何か不足や間違いを起こした可能性が大きいので、それらを詳しくチェックするか、参照先で紹介されている[Flutter大学](https://flutteruniv.com/)のサイトにソースコードやサポート窓口があるか問い合わせてみてはどうでしょう？